# Maplibre-gl-js 2.1.6 Missing .g files in gitHub repository

Tags: github, maplibre-gl

I'm trying to get the maplibre 2.1.6 development code from the github repository so I can develop locally, which I have done before with version 1.14. I get the repository .zip file. When I try a build, it fails with messages that .g files can not be found.
This is an example:
loaded rollup.config.ts with warnings
(!) Plugin typescript: @rollup/plugin-typescript TS2307: Cannot find module './array_types.g' or its corresponding type declarations.

I can not find the files in the github.com repository!  Where could they be??

In the past with missing files, when I see them I can grab them off the site. Or, I can get them with a local install of the particular module. Not this time. I don't even know who to ask at maplibre or github. Any ideas?

Comment: I SOLVED IT.  I found the files by doing an npm install of maplibre-gl  AFTER I updated node.js getting all the tools. Then I copied all the .g.ts files I found there to my local repository directory and it worked. I was able to build.

Comment: AND, upon studying the .g.ts I see that they are generated by build/generate-*-.ts code so that is why they are missing in the repository. Who knew

Answer (score 0):

I see that they are generated by build/generate-*-.ts code so that is why they are missing in the repository.